# Google Cloud - Two clusters in the same project belong to the same VPC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

How do I set up two clusters in the same GCP project such that they share the same VPC?

I created a cluster with Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancer (without Global Access) in a cluster, say C1. I then created cluster C2 in the same zone and same project. I assumed doing so would guarantee that the clusters are in the same VPC.

However, from cluster C2, when I do:

`kubectl exec -it busybox -- ping ${INTERNAL_LB_IP}`, it is not reachable..

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achieve with your test. What the current kubeconfig?

Comment: 1. They will be in the same VPC as long as you select the same VPC for both

Comment: 2. the internal load balancer is a TCP load balancer, not ICMP. try to curl the LB internal IP

Comment: 3. Depending on how you configured the cluster, there might be a rule in the iptables of each node that considers 10.0.0.0/8 as being internal to the cluster so the traffic may not reach the other cluster. Please provide more details about how each cluster was created